# CssClass duplicates on an UpdatePanel update

Tags: .net, asp.net, updatepanel, duplicates, css

I've got a simple user control in my ASP.NET Webforms project which inherits from the LinkButton.  It's got a property to change the size, which just adds some predefined CSS classes to the control.

```
Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
    Dim SizeClass As String = String.Empty
    If Size = SizeEnum.Large Then
        SizeClass = "large"
    Else
        SizeClass = "small"
    End If

    Me.CssClass += " button " + SizeClass

    Me.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(String.Format("<span class=""l"">{0}</span><span class=""r""></span><span class=""clear""></span>", Me.Text)))
    MyBase.CreateChildControls()
End Sub
```

Pretty simple, right?  So when it renders the class property is something like `class="button small"`.

When this control is placed inside an update panel along with some other things, when the update panel updates the class property for every one of these controls becomes `class=" button small button small button small button small button small button small button small button small button small button small button small button small button small"`

Which is a little bit rediculous.  Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
Me.CssClass += " button " + SizeClass
```

to

```
Me.CssClass = " button " + SizeClass
```

Each time the control renders, the CssClass is stored in ViewState of the control. So when it renders it keeps appending.

Comment: Well, I still would like the ability to add whatever CssClass I might need to on the front end, which is why I'm adding to the existing CssClass instead of just setting it.

Comment: You could try disabling the ViewState of the control?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. it was a viewstate issue and disabling that fixed it!